# unable to call external api in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, request, node-modules

I am trying to call an external API from my Node platform, but I am not getting expected result.

I have tried with npm request module and to convert my postfield data query string. I tried to set `JSON: true`, but I am not getting the result.

```js
var request = require('request');
var querystring = require('querystring');

// api_call function
api_call_with_data = function(url, form_data) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    request.post({              
              uri: url,
              headers: {
                "content-type": "application/json"
              },
              body: form_data,
              method: 'POST',
              json: true
            }, (err, res, final_res) => {            
              if (err) reject(err)
              resolve(final_res)
            });
        })
    };

app.get('/call_api', (req, res) => { 

    var api_url = "http://www.example.com/api/test";

    var api_form = {
        "first_name": "Stack",
        "last_name": "Overflow",
        "email_id": "test@example.com"
    };

    var formData = querystring.stringify(api_form);

    api_call_with_data(api_url, formData)
    .then(response => {

        res.send(response);


    })
    .catch(error => {
        res.send(error)
    })

});
```

I am getting the error:

```
{"library":"digital envelope routines","function":"EVP_DecryptFinal_ex","reason":"wrong final block length","code":"ERR_OSSL_EVP_WRONG_FINAL_BLOCK_LENGTH"}
```

Expected result:

```
{'status' : 'success', "api_response" : "Thank you to call API"}
```

Comment: `json: true` means that the request is sending JSON (also adds the header Content-type: application/json). Remove that

Comment: @KiJéy, I tried with headers : Content-type:application/json and application/x-www-form-urlencoded Both AND json:true and false both but i am not getting result

Comment: After googling your error, it seems that the problem has nothing to do with with your HTTP request code. It's either a problem with SSL or maybe somewhere else in your code if you're encrypting or decrypting data.